# Min character length, strlen?

Tags: php, syntax

```
if (strlen($comment > 2)) {
```

Ok, so I only want to exec this if $comment consist of more than 2 characters
I believe strlen should do this, but it doesn't. Am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your closing parenthesis is in the wrong place:

```
if (strlen($comment) > 2) {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know php.
But perhaps you should try

```
if (strlen($comment) > 2) {
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
if (strlen( $comment ) > 2 ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

should be:

```
if ( strlen($comment) > 2 ) {
```

You might also want to trim() the comment as well to make sure it's more than two non-whitespace characters:

```
if ( strlen(trim($comment)) > 2 ) {
```